# Laravel Routes To Undefined

Tags: php, laravel

I have a redirection code that looks like this

```
return redirect()->route('matters', ['clientid' => $client_id]);
```

and in web.php, I have this route definition

```
Route::get('/matters/{clientid}', [
  'as' => 'matters',
  'uses' => 'MattersController@show'
]);
```

This does not redirect me to `matters` but to `undefined`.

**Questions**

1. Why is that and
2. How can I ensure that it takes me to `matters/someIdHere`?

I have also tried this

```
Route::get('/matters/{clientid}', 'MattersController@show');
```

and redirecting like this

```
redirect('matters/' . $client_id);
```

also, this does not work.

When I run `php artisan route:list --path=matters`, I get the following
[image]

Comment: Have you already checked that $client_id has a correct value? have you checked the generated HTML?

Comment: Also check what `Client` model is returning in the `getRouteKeyName` function if defined

Comment: @dparoli Yes, I have. even when i hardcode the value, doesn't work

Comment: dd($client_id) to ensure there is a client id, do this at the controller

Comment: Please check that you don't have any other route declaration that overwrite or shadow the one you posted.

Comment: Tried dd($client_id), didn't make a difference. Also checked my routes, they are all unique

Comment: did u get any data when u dd()

Comment: use `php artisan route:list --path=matters` and see correct route name

Comment: Please try to remove hasTeam middleware from the route declaration.

Comment: Just tried it. Still same behavior

Comment: You probably have some other problem in your controller function, try to only redirect and comment out any other code in there.

Answer (score 0):

add name to route

```
 Route::get('matters/{clientid}', 'MattersController@show')->name('matters');
```

check clientid in controller :

```
dd($client_id);

return redirect()->route('matters', ['clientid' => $client_id]);
```

clear route cache :

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: It's already a named route the OP is using `'as' => 'matters'`

Comment: Yeah, this does not solve it. Im still taken to `undefined`

Comment: Giving it a shot

Comment: Okay that didnt make a difference

Comment: what is `dd($client_id);` print ?

Comment: It does not print anything. But I doubt if that is even a problem because the behavior is the same even when I have hardcoded the id

Comment: `It does not print anything.` ---  this is the problem , route declaration syntax is correct , id is not being passed

Comment: make sure clientid has value